# How to know the parent of table from child table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL which contains many tables, some tables are linked with INHERITANCE (for example table `Base` is the parent of table `Child`).

In table `Child` we can find the `Id` of the parent `Base`, my question is how can I know the name of the parent `Base` when looping through the `Child` rows and columns?

I want to send a PostgreSQL command for example

```
std::string parent_name = db.exec("SELECT from Child WHERE .... )
```

and the parent_name (here string) should return `Base`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually go and [read the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
=> CREATE TABLE tp (i int);
=> CREATE TABLE tc () INHERITS (tp);

=> SELECT i.*, cl1.relname AS child, cl2.relname AS parent
FROM
    pg_inherits i
    JOIN pg_class cl1 ON i.inhrelid = cl1.oid
    JOIN pg_class cl2 ON i.inhparent = cl2.oid
;
┌──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ inhrelid │ inhparent │ inhseqno │ inhdetachpending │ child │ parent │
├──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────┼───────┼────────┤
│   124720 │    124717 │        1 │ f                │ tc    │ tp     │
└──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
(1 row)
```